# ion-list item click and navigate

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

how to make my ion-list clickable and show details page to show more details about the clicked item

I will make another page like details to handle the details data

but how can I make the list clickable and show another page which have the details
**my ads page .html which has the ion-list**

```html
<ion-header>
  
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
My App
    </ion-title>
    
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-item-divider>
    <ion-label color="dark">
Latest Ads
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-list *ngFor="let item of dataArray">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://mysite.co/uploads/{{ item.document }}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
            <h2 color="primary">{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <h3>{{ item.city }}</h3>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>




  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
              <!-- Tab bar -->
              <ion-tabs>
                <ion-tab-bar>
                  <ion-tab-button routerLink="/menu">
                    <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-tab-button>
                  <ion-tab-button routerLink="/contactus">
                    <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-tab-button>
                </ion-tab-bar>
              </ion-tabs>
                    <!-- Tab bar -->
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
```

**my ads page .ts file**

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adspage',
  templateUrl: './adspage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adspage.page.scss'],
})
export class AdspagePage implements OnInit {

  dataArray;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://mysite.co/reset-api.php').subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.dataArray = response;
});

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`<ion-item button="true" (click)="showDetail()"`
```

then you can initialize function showDetail in component.ts file

Answer (score 0):

On HTML make this changes:

```
`<ion-list *ngFor="let item of dataArray">`
```

must be

```
`<ion-list *ngFor="let item of dataArray; let i = index">`
```

And

```
`<ion-item>`
```

must be 
    `<ion-item (click)="goDetail(i);">`

On ts file you must this method:

```
`goDetail(num: value){
    console.log("go to page " + num);
    // Add here the code to navigate: e.g this.router.navigate(['page'];
    // You would must import import { Router } from '@angular/router';
}`
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can add routerLink now:

```
<ion-item
  routerLink="/item/details">
```

You do need to make sure it has a matching route in the routing module.